# hashes memory usage is higher than instagram test result

Tags: python, redis, instagram

hi all I am new to redis and I am following instagram engineering blog for optimization purpose.I tested memory usage for 1 milion keys storage through hashes(1000 hashes having 1000 keys each).According to Instagram post [here](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value) it took only 16MB of storage space but my test took 38MB.can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is my test code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import redis
#pool=redis.ConnectionPool(host=127.0.0.1,port=6379,db=4)
NUM_ENTRIES=1000000
MAX_VAL=12000000
def createData(min,max,userId):
        r_server=redis.Redis(host='localhost',port=6379,db=5)
        p=r_server.pipeline()
        for i in xrange(0,1000):
                for j in xrange(0,1000):
                        p.hset('follower:%s' % (i),j,j)
        p.execute()
        size = int(r_server.info()['used_memory'])
        print '%s bytes, %s MB' % (size, size / 1024 / 1024)
```

redis info :

```
# Server
redis_version:2.8.9
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:a9b5dff7da49156c
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.19.0-15-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.9.2
process_id:11037
run_id:c069c22be15f6b7cbd6490cea6d4ca497d8ad7cb
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:230666
uptime_in_days:2
hz:10
lru_clock:8643496
config_file:

# Clients
connected_clients:1
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:41186920
used_memory_human:39.28M
used_memory_rss:60039168
used_memory_peak:256243984
used_memory_peak_human:244.37M
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.46
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.2.0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1434659507
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:0
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok

# Stats
total_connections_received:21
total_commands_processed:3010067
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:10
keyspace_misses:0
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:2774

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:264.43
used_cpu_user:110.01
used_cpu_sys_children:0.27
used_cpu_user_children:1.55

# Keyspace
db5:keys=1000,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Comment: Could you also provide the output of your database's `INFO memory` as well as the configuration directives `hash-max-ziplist-entries` and `hash-max-ziplist-value`?

Comment: @ItamarHaber hash-max-ziplist-entries 512 and
hash-max-ziplist-value 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to your server using the default setting of `hash-max-ziplist-entries` since you're store 1000 fields - here's a little test I ran using your snippet:

```
foo@bar:/tmp$ redis-cli config get hash-max-ziplist-entries
1) "hash-max-ziplist-entries"
2) "512"
foo@bar:/tmp$ time python so.py 
56791944 bytes, 54 MB

real    0m23.225s
user    0m18.574s
sys 0m0.377s
foo@bar:/tmp$ redis-cli config set hash-max-ziplist-entries 1000
OK
foo@bar:/tmp$ redis-cli flushall
OK
foo@bar:/tmp$ time python so.py 
9112080 bytes, 8 MB

real    0m28.928s
user    0m18.663s
sys 0m0.315s
```

Comment: .Thanx it solved my problem.I have only question.does it has any cons If I increase hash-max-ziplist-entries value?

Comment: Just the usual space time tradeoff (RAM vs CPU) :)